# Bash Awk Select lines from a file with columns in common present in several other files

Tags: bash, csv, awk, compare

I have a folder with tab-separator .tsv files like this:

**Sample_1.tsv file:**

```
Gene    Center  Start   End Strand  Ref Sample  ID_Sample   HGVps   Other_Columns
AAA .   111111  111111  +   T   C   Test    p.A123B NA
AAA .   111112  111112  +   C   A   Test    p.C456D NA
BBB .   222222  222222  +   A   T   Test    p.E789F NA
CCC .   333331  333331  +   G   C   Test    p.G10H  NA
CCC .   333332  333332  +   A   T   Test    p.I11J  NA
CCC .   333333  333333  +   T   C   Test    p.K12L  NA
```

And I have in another folder several files for each gene (called later as Genes.tsv).

**AAA.tsv file for AAA gene:**

```
Coordinates Some_col_1  Change  Some_col_2  Consequence Other_Columns
chr1:111111-111111  NA  chr1:g.111111T>C    NA  Ms AAA A123B    NA
```

**BBB.tsv file for BBB gene:**

```
Coordinates Some_col_1  Change  Some_col_2  Consequence Other_Columns
chr2:222222-222222  NA  chr2:g.222222A>T    NA  Syn BBB E789F   NA
```

**CCC.tsv file for CCC gene:**

```
Coordinates Some_col_1  Change  Some_col_2  Consequence Other_Columns
chr3:333332-333332  NA  chr3:g.333332A>T    NA  Nns CCC I11J    NA
chr3:333339-333339  NA  chr3:g.333339T>C    NA  Syn CCC K12L    NA
```

*etc. for other genes.*

Note that in the "Consequences" column there are three elements separated by spaces including the name of the Gene and the HGVps code I'm interested in.

I put here these simplified tables as an example but I have more columns in reality. See the following images for the correct column number:

[Image-1:Sample_1.tsv_with_correct_column_numbers](https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/42/l87a.png)
(**NB:** In yellow are the lines I want to keep.)

[Image-2:Genes.tsv_with_correct_column_numbers](https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/42/me3p.png)
(**NB:** In green are the elements in common with Sample_1.)

Basically, I want to save in a new file all the rows of Sample_1.tsv that have columns present in the other Genes.tsv files. The criterion is either the **Genes Columns+Start+End+Ref+Sample** are the same or the **HVps column only** if the other columns do not match.

**What I want to obtain:**

```
Gene    Center  Start   End Strand  Ref Sample  ID_Sample   HGVps   Other_Columns
AAA .   111111  111111  +   T   C   Test    p.A123B NA
BBB .   222222  222222  +   A   T   Test    p.E789F NA
CCC .   333332  333332  +   A   T   Test    p.I11J  NA
CCC .   333333  333333  +   T   C   Test    p.K12L  NA
```

I think it is possible to use bash/awk/grep to select lines of interest.

I don't exactly know how to do this but I guess that the way to proceed should be something like this:

```
Create a new file called Sample_1_ok.tsv
Add column names in Sample_1_ok.tsv

If Gene+Start+End+Ref+Sample columns from Sample_1.tsv are the same in Genes.tsv files:
Append Sample_1.tsv line in Sample_1_ok.tsv

Else if HGVps column from Sample_1.tsv is the same in Genes.tsv files:
Append Sample_1.tsv line in Sample_1_ok.tsv
```

Do you have any advice on how to proceed?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: how many of the `<gene>.tsv` files are you looking to process? could you provide some detail on which values match which column names in the `<gene>.tsv` files (eg, there are 3x copies of `111111` in `AAA.tsv` ... which is the `Start` and which is the `End`)? have you tested any code and if so could you please share it?  first idea would be `awk` ... parse the `<gene>.fsv` viles into an array and then process `Sample_1.fsv` for a match in the array; if 'too many' `<gene>.fsv` files then maybe reformat `<gene>.fsv` data into single file w/ same format as `Sample_1.fsv` and then `comm` the data

Comment: I have ~ 50 `<gene>.tsv` files. For the detail of the columns of the `<gene>.tsv` files, the column `Coordinates` corresponds to `chr#:Start-End coordinates`. As it is a single letter mutation, `Start` and `End` are often the same (but this is not always the case, that's why I want to distinguish the two coordinates). The `Change` column, I only want to get the two capital letters just before and after the `>` symbol. The first of these two letters corresponds to `Ref` and the second to `Sample`. At least the column `Consequence` contains the name of `Gene` (AAA, BBB, CCC,...) and the `HGVps`.

Comment: @markp-fuso  By using awk match, I extracted the columns of interest from `<gene>.tsv` : `awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'match($1, /([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)/, a) && match($3, /(.)>(.)/, b) && match($5, /([A-Z]+) ([A-Z][0-9]+[A-Z])/, c) {print c[1],a[1],a[2],b[1],b[2],c[2]}' <gene>.tsv > <gene_filtered>.tsv`
So the next step would be to compare `Sample_1.tsv` and these new tables?

Comment: fwiw, I would recommend moving your `awk` code up into the question; makes it easier for others to understand the question if they don't have to go digging through comments trying to piece everything together

Comment: @markp-fuso Ok I will remember your recommendation for the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One (somewhat verbose) `awk` solution:

```
awk '
/Consequence/   { gfmt=1 ; next }                          # header record of a "<gene>.tsv" file so flag as needing to parse based on a g(ene) file format; skip to next line of input
/ID_Sample/     { gfmt=0 }                                 # header record of "Sample_1.tsv" file so clear g(ene) file format flag; continue to process this line of input

# gfmt==1 => parse data based on the g(ene) file format

gfmt            { gene=$6                                  # parse out gene name

                  split($1,a,/[:-]/)                       # parse out start and end values
                  gstart=a[2]
                  gend=a[3]

                  split($3,a,">")                          # parse out ref and sample values
                  gref=substr(a[1],length(a[1]),1)         # assumes ref is always a single character
                  gsample=a[2]

                  hgvps="p."$7                             # parse out HGVps and prefix with "p."; assumes prefix is always "p."

                  garray[gene,gstart,gend,gref,gsample]    # use fields as multidimensional index; to be used for testing a match based on gene data
                  hgarray[gene,hgvps]                      # use fields as multidimentional index; to be used for testing a match based on HGVps
                }

# gfmt==0 => parse data based on Sample_1.tsv file format

! gfmt          { if ( FNR==1 ) { print $0 ; next }        # print header record; skip to next line of input

                  gene=$1                                  # parse out gene values;
                  gstart=$3                                # could use field numbers in the
                  gend=$4                                  # follow-on "if" logic but wanted
                  gref=$6                                  # to give names to fields
                  gsample=$7                               # as form of documentation 

                  hgvps=$9

                  # if we have an index match in either array then print the current line to stdout

                  if ( (gene,gstart,gend,gref,gsample) in garray || (gene,hgvps) in hgarray )
                      { print $0 } 
                }

' *.tsv xx/Sample_1.tsv
```

**NOTES**:

- remove comments to declutter code.
- OP could swap in the `awk/match` code for parsing out the `<gene>.tsv` columns
- the above code is run from the directory where the `<gene>.tsv` files reside
- the above code assumes all `<gene>.tsv` files are to be processed (hence the `'*.tsv'`)
- the `Sample_1.tsv` file is the last file fed to `awk`; in this case my `Sample_1.tsv` file is in a separate sub-directory

Running the above against `AAA.tsv`, `BBB.tsv`, `CCC.tsv` and `xx/Sample_1.tsv` generates the following output:

```
Gene    Center  Start   End Strand  Ref Sample  ID_Sample   HGVps   Other_Columns
AAA .   111111  111111  +   T   C   Test    p.A123B NA
BBB .   222222  222222  +   A   T   Test    p.E789F NA
CCC .   333332  333332  +   A   T   Test    p.I11J  NA
CCC .   333333  333333  +   T   C   Test    p.K12L  NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer and for showing me an interesting way to compare two files with different structure. It worked perfectly for my example tables.

As you mentioned, I have changed the names of the columns in the `awk/match` code in order to distinguish `<gene>.tsv` and `Sample_1.tsv` files. And it worked.

The difficult part of the code I meet with my real data was to select the gene name and the hgvps code, which were present into the same cell and separated with a space. I prefered to use supplemental `awk match` expression to select them. I also added the `awk -F'\t'`paramater at the beginning.

Here are my modifications of the script (all of them are present in the first part):

```
awk -F'\t' '
/Consequence/   { gfmt=1 ; next }
/ID_Sample/     { gfmt=0 }

# gfmt==1 => parse data based on the g(ene) file format

gfmt==1           { match($5, / ([A-Z0-9]{2,})/, a)
                  gene=a[1]
                  print gene

                  split($1,a,/[:-]/)
                  gstart=a[2]
                  gend=a[3]

                  split($3,a,">")
                  gref=substr(a[1],length(a[1]),1)
                  gsample=a[2]

                  match($5, /([A-Z][0-9]+[A-Z])/, a)
                  hgvps="p," a[1]

                  garray[gene,gstart,gend,gref,gsample]
                  hgarray[gene,hgvps]

                }
# gfmt==0 => parse data based on Sample_1.tsv file format

gfmt==0           { if ( FNR==1 ) { print $0 ; next }

                  gene=$1
                  gstart=$3
                  gend=$4
                  gref=$6
                  gsample=$7

                  hgvps=$9
                  if ( (gene,gstart,gend,gref,gsample) in garray || (gene,hgvps) in hgarray )
                      { print $0 }
                }

' *.tsv xx/Sample_1.tsv
```

Thanks again for your help!